# How can I get Html.CheckBox() as boolean during POST in custom IModelBinder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using `Html.CheckBox()`.  The resulting HTML is:

```
<input id="IsMultiGraph" name="IsMultiGraph" value="true" type="checkbox">
<input name="IsMultiGraph" value="false" type="hidden">
```

On the server I have an Action which is accepting the form post information and using a custom IModelBinder to bind the form results to one of my models.  Here is a snippet of the code I am running in the IModelBinder:

```
bool isMultiGraph;
if (!bool.TryParse(bindingContext.HttpContext.Request["IsMultiGraph"], out isMultiGraph))
    bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError("IsMultiGraph", "Invalid boolean for \"IsMultiGraph\""); //this should not ever happen unless someone is programatically posting
result.IsMultiGraph = isMultiGraph;
```

The problem is that since `Html.CheckBox()` is rendering a checkbox as well as a hidden input field if I change the state of the textbox the postback value is doubled (ie. "true,false").

I understand why this is done and I'm looking for the best way to parse the current value of the CheckBox during a postback (checked = true, unchecked = false).  Is there another helper method in MVC for this or should I just write my own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use the `GetValues` method of the `NameValueCollection` class in order to get the first value of the array property like this:

```
bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.GetValues("IsMultiGraph")[0]
```

Comment: That'll work, anyone know how ASP.NET MVC does it in their default binder.  It seems like CheckBoxes are a special case.  Maybe I was to tired, but I couldn't see where they were handling the checkbox and hidden input last night.